# Incorrect accessibility focus order for nested elements in React Native

Tags: react-native, accessibility, react-native-ios

I'm working in a mixed-match app where we use React Native components for a few modules. In this case, I've a tableview in which we add RN components in a few of the cells.

I was able to enable accessibility for nested elements in those React Native components but the order of focus seems to be incorrect when added in a UITableView.

The view hierarchy would be like the below:

```
 <E0>
    <E1 accessible={true}>
       <E11 accessible={true}>
       <E12 accessible={true}>...
    <E2 accessible={true}>
       <E21 accessible={true}>
       <E22 accessible={true}>...
```

I'm expecting the focus order to be
**E1**, E11, E12, **E2**, E21, E22

but it's announcing in the order
**E1, E2**, E11, E12, E21, E22
ie, parent elements and then child elements

In iOS we have the `accessibilityElements` property to set the order. Is there any way to set the focus order like that in React Native, or is there any other way to achieve that?

**P.S.**: The same component works as expected, (ie. voiceover is announced in the correct order) when I display the particular component in a view controller.

Any timely help / useful suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I've spent more than a couple of days in this issue.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We transitioned our app to more of a green field RN app where we are not facing issues like this again. That might be the only solution AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that people with a screen reader enabled does not use their visual as much, you can shift around the elements, making the screen reader read them in the right order.

In your case that would mean **if** the screen reader is enabled, then add a `marginTop` of for instance `50` to `E2`

Here's an example: Left is when the screenreader is enabled.

[image]

Checking whether the screen reader is enabled can be done with: [AccessibilityInfo](https://reactnative.dev/docs/accessibilityinfo#isscreenreaderenabled)

Dislaimer: I know this is a rather ridicules answer, since it just avoids the issue instead of solving it, but I'm posting it anyway, because it did solve a similar problem to yours and it seems there is no solution coming from React Native.

Answer (score 0):

While [Nicolai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63919849/9154668) might achieve an acceptable result, in terms of whether there is a way to actually set the screen reader focus order in React Native:

- Not within React Native itself, which is disappointing. See the beginning of [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/discussions/389) discussion.

There are some non-core potential solutions:

- [This gist](https://gist.github.com/louy/6b66c45ae47bb4e3bac5a104dd0649ff) for an A11y Wrapper.
- [The react-native-a11y package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-a11y), in beta as of late 2023, that allows you to set screen reader focus order.